# Is it possible to replace if x > 0 to while x?

Tags: python

I'm just wondering if the `if n > 0` could be replaced by `while n:` instead?

```
result = []
def func(n):
    if n > 0 :
        result.insert(0, n%10)
        func(n//10)

    return result
```

Comment: What is `jay`? Did you mean to do `func`?

Comment: Why don't you try it?  Of course you would then end-up with an infinite loop, since you don't appear to change `n` inside it.

Comment: You could replace ```n > 0``` with ```n``` (as long as you're confident ```n``` will never be negative), but ```while``` and ```if``` are not the same thing.

Comment: First of all @Andrew Li is right what is jay? And according to your question while and if are two different constructs

Comment: oops....my fault. Should be func not jay

Comment: DO you mean replacing the recursion with a `while` loop?  That can usually be done, but you need to rewrite, not just replace one statement.

Comment: @cdarke: That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = []
def func(n):
    while n > 0 :
        result.insert(0, n%10)
        n = n//10

    return result

print(func(4210))
```

Gives:

```
[4, 2, 1, 0]
```

You could get the same result with:

```
result = [int(n) for n in str(4210)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to replace `if n > 0:` with `while n:` because the body of the loop doesn't change *n*.  That implies that the loop will never terminate, which won't be useful in this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(n):
    result.insert(0, n%10)
    func(n//10)
    n -= 1
```

Should work.

Comment: That's not the purpose of this function. It aims on putting all single digits of an input numeric value into a list.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't make that replacement. The reason why is because

```
while n:
```

would be equivalent to

```
while n == True:
```